# Aspnet Core MVC application with spotify authentication callback url redirecting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, callback, spotify

I'm building an aspnet core web application and want to allow my users to authenticate using their Spotify accounts. I've managed to get the auth flow working as expected when running locally but when I deploy and am using my domain the callback url is: `http://127.0.0.1/callback`.

Heres the configuration for external auth:

```
        services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddSpotify(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "blahblah";
            options.ClientSecret = "blahblah";
            options.CallbackPath = "/callback";
            options.Scope.Add("user-follow-read");
```

As you can see, `options.CallbackPath` is `/callback` so i'm assuming this is appended to the hosted domain from the server?

My configuration looks like this:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM
- Application running in a Docker container, listening on port 80 (no https)
- Nginx server configured as a reverse proxy for my domain
- Lets encrypt issuing SSL certificates for nginx
- Spotify redirect url set to `https://example.com/callback` and `http//:localhost:5001/callback`

I have tried:

- Setting `.UseUrls("https://example.com")` in `program.cs`
- Various different combinations of redirect urls in spotify's app configuration

Is there a way I can specify the host within the `spotify authentication options` or maybe theres some magic I can do within nginx to help with the callback?

Thanks

Comment: What is the component you're using for your Spotify Authentication?

Comment: i'm using `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify`

Comment: added my thoughts in an answer below. hope it helps

Comment: Did the answer below help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the domain for your deployed instance - so if there's an address to load your response on the web that's what you'll need to use instead of 127.0.0.1 as that's your local machine which works fine when running locally but once deployed you must use the deployed address instead

Comment: How can I specify the domain? The only options I can see for spotifyauth is `            options.CallbackPath = "/callback";` which throws an exception if I enter a domain: `'The path in 'value' must start with '/'.'`

Answer (score 0):

I've use a slightly different component in the past but the same *should* apply...

For the callback path you should just set it to:

On Spotify 
- http://[yourlocaldomain]:[port]/signin-spotify
- http://yourlocaldomain.com/signin-spotify

The component you're using will set `/signin-spotify` as default for `CallbackPath` so you don't need to set it in your `services.AddAuthentication().AddSpotify(options =>...` setup.

Then in your controller your 'ExternalLogin' should look something like this...

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("externallogincallback", "account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

where `provider` = `Spotify` and `returnUrl` = *the local path location you want to go after the sign up is complete (e.g. '/home/welcome')*.

The user will be returned to `account/externallogincallback` in this example after logging in to Spotify. The  `externallogincallback` does the sign up stuff then pushes the user on to the url specified in `returnUrl`.